# Switching to a tab in TabControl using code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol in my application that has several tabs in it.

I want to automatically switch to another tab when the "Next" button is pressed.

I cannot figure out how to change which tab is visible programmatically.

```
    private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change to the next tab
        tabControl1.???;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TabControl.SelectedTab` property. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = anotherTab;
```

But you can also use the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` property. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
try
{
    tabControl1.SelectedIndex += 1;
}
catch
{
    //This prevents the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular scenario you can use `SelectedIndex` property of the `TabControl`. This gives you an integer representing the index of the currently selected tab. Likewise you can set a tab as selected by setting an integer value to this property.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int currentTabIndex = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
   currentTabIndex++;
   if (currentTabIndex < tabControl1.TabCount)
   {
      tabControl1.SelectedIndex = currentTabIndex;
   }
   else
   {
     btnNext.Enabled=false;
   }
}
```